# Json data returns undefined eventhough it exists

Tags: json, node.js

im trying to use seneca for microservice stuffs. im new and inexperience in this field. i have a problem where my json object received is undefined but it shows in the console.log.

```
 console.log("company:", body.data.company)
 company = body.data.company
```

and this is the error result. it shows that it the company clearly contains a value and not a null

> company: BST
>   {"notice":"seneca: Action cmd:addMember,role:client failed: company is not defined.","code":"act_execute","err":{"eraro":true,"orig":{},
>   "code":"act_execute","seneca":true,"package":"seneca","msg":"seneca: Action cmd:addMember,role:client failed: company is not defined. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above provided information i can tell that company field not defined means it is not present into **body.data**

try printing **body** on console and check the whole incoming data.

Comment: you can actually see that it actually was printed.. the console log preview is the one at the bottom. it shows company : BST as it should be but the error next is due to the variable being passed an undefined parameters.

Comment: body.data :  { company: 'BST',
  person:
   { fullname: 'Laura Kurniawan',
     sex: 'Female',
     position: 'Senior Designer' } }

{"notice":"seneca: Action cmd:addMember,role:client failed: Cannot read property 'company' of undefined.

this is the console log that i copied. the top shows the json data while the bottom shows the error. sorry if there are any wrongdoings in the formatting as i am new to stackoverflow 

@Nilasis Sen

Comment: yes you are doing it correctly .  body.data.company should get company . maybe some other issue can't say much more .